# refresher isnt ending and getting an error when pulled down again

Tags: swift, parse-platform, refresh, pull-to-refresh

i am using Swift and im trying to add a pull to refresh function for my table but it wont stop refreshing i think i may have a problem with my endrefresher also when its refreshing and wont stop when you pull to refresh again the app crashes with a NSexception error. How can i end the refresh and have the refresh the page and avoid the crashing if its pulled down again?
heres my code as well:

```
class HomePage: UITableViewController  {

    var images = [UIImage]()
    var titles = [String]()
    var imageFile = [PFFile]()
    var votingObjects: [PFObject] = []
    var objectIds = [""]

    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        refresher = UIRefreshControl()

        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

        refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

        func refresh() {

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.limit = 15
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil  {
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                println(objects!)
                for objectRow in objects! {
                    let object = objectRow as! PFObject


                    if let objectIds = object["objectId"] as? String {
                        self.objectIds.append(objectIds)
                    }
                    if let title = object["Title"] as? String {
                        self.titles.append(title)
                    }
                    if let imgFile = object["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.imageFile.append(imgFile)
                    }
                    self.votingObjects.append(object)
                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableView.reloadData() // Updating the tableView on the main thread - important. Do some research on Grand Central Dispatch :)

                })
            } else {
                println(error)
                // Error
            }
        }
    }

        refresh()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the refresher to call the function refresh when it finish:

```
refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

So we need to implement that function:

```
func refresh(){
    println("Refresh")
    refresher.endRefreshing()
}
```

Now this function will be called and the refresher will stop

Comment: its still doing the same thing should i try taking all my code form viewDidLoad out?

Comment: Sorry I just saw the problem I update the answer, that should fix it!

Comment: it still seems to be doing the same thing